# If function in excel to find weekends

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to do an in function in excel where it sets the cell value to "Yes" whether the day of the week is Saturday or Sunday otherwise it sets the cell value to "No".

I'm using this: `=if((OR($P1="Saturday",$P1="Sunday"),"Yes","No"))` but I get a formula error, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dates are in date format - something like `1/1/2017` you can use  the `WEEKDAY` function

```
=IF(WEEKDAY($P$1,2)>5,"Yes","No")
```

The `TEXT` function also works - it's more flexible

```
=IF(LEFT(TEXT($P$1,"ddd"))="S","Yes","No")
```

Comment: Isn't the `TEXT` function language dependent?

Comment: I suspect so.. OP's example was in English so I was happy enough to give that as a solution. I also only meant more flexible in the sense that you can adapt it to month/year names etc if needed

Answer (score 0):

To examine them as text, you must use text:

```
=IF(OR(TEXT($P1,"dddd")="Saturday",TEXT($P1,"dddd")="Sunday"),"Yes","No")
```